# How can I diagnose my very slow Ruby startup times?

Tags: ruby, macos

Intermittently, when I type a command that involves Ruby (like `ruby somefile.rb`, `rake`, `rspec spec`, or `irb`), it takes a long time for the command to execute. For example, a few minutes ago, it took about a minute for `irb` to start. A few seconds ago, it took about a second.

While waiting for `irb` to start, I pressed `Control + T` repeatedly. Some output I saw included:

```
load: 1.62  cmd: ruby 12374 uninterruptible 0.45u 0.13s
load: 1.62  cmd: ruby 12374 uninterruptible 0.48u 0.13s
load: 1.62  cmd: ruby 12374 uninterruptible 0.53u 0.15s
```

[On OSX, this output represents](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050520120407161) "load, command running, pid, status, and user and system CPU time used". It appears that when I had been waiting 53 seconds, the CPU time used was only 0.15 seconds.

My understanding of load is that [it's roughly "how many cores are being used"](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages). Eg, on a one-core system, 1.0 is full utilization, but on a four-core machine, it's 25% utilization. I don't think the amount of load is the problem, because my machine is multi-core. Also, when `irb` starts quickly, I can get one line of output with `Control + T` that's also above `1.0`.

```
load: 1.22  cmd: ruby 12452 running 0.26u 0.02s
```

I also notice that in the good case, the status is "running", not "uninterruptible".

How can I diagnose and fix these slow startups?

Comment: "Uninterruptible" makes me think it's stuck in I/O. Could just be slow disk, if it gets faster on subsequent executions. I came to the comments to ask: What's the ruby version? (`ruby -v`)

Comment: @Satya - Ruby 2.1.2p95. Further research says it's probably waiting on an IO system call. Maybe I can use some kind of dtrace tool to see what.

Comment: Yup, dtrace. I'm not sure what trace tools are available on OSX, so I didn't say. Anyway, I wanted to see if it was something dumb like one of those slow-`require` versions of ruby (1.9.2? 1.8.7?).

Comment: Looks like `dtruss -n process_name` might work if I can catch it happening again. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html on this specifically, and http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/ for more general info

Comment: I've added a shell alias, `function diagnose() { sudo dtruss -cade -p "$1" }`, so I can type `diagnose 1234` (the pid) next time I see it happening

Comment: I'd recommend moving this question to the [apple.se] site. While the question is related to development, the cause, and fix, is most likely to be found there as it's more likely to be an OS or hardware level problem.

Comment: Have you checked your `.irbrc`? Maybe it takes too long to execute it.

Comment: @hakcho good thought, but the same happens for `rspec spec` or `rake` or `ruby somefile.rb`

Comment: What about the old safe way (uninstall and re-install ruby) ? Try with rbenv.

Comment: Make sure you're using terminal and not iterm2. I had a similar problem with iTerm on my macbook pro (2011). 

Other possibilities could be :

 - slowing / faulty hard drive
 - not enough available RAM
 - too many processes running in the background

Answer (score 1):

#### This is a longshot. Try installing `haveged`.

- http://freecode.com/projects/haveged

I've seen this problem before. That solved it for me. Sometimes there is not enough entropy for libraries or elements of Ruby which are trying to load up a pool of random numbers.

If you notice that the time for something to start goes quickly when you are typing more, moving your mouse, using a lot of network traffic -- then it's entropy, which would go against most of what you'd think.

If there is more processor and RAM usage, more interaction with the system, etc - you'd think it'd be slower, but in entropy depletion situations, that's actually exactly what you need.

Comment: I just learned about this today - it's not very likely on a laptop, but it is more and more likely in any kind of virtual machine - which might be what Mr. Long was using. Do try moving the mouse or pulling up a different app and resizing windows.